# Change the color of the specific number of percents of the total width in a <div> element

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass two values into the width of a div and paint that many percent of the total fixed size width, with the specific color, something like in the example bellow.

```
  <div style="width: 100px; background-color: red (@Model.value1)%; background-color:green (@Model.value2)%"></div>
```

This is something similar to a progress bar, all i need is to have two 3 different colors, value 1 in percents, value 2 in percents and the rest if there is any. Is this achievable?

Comment: Not clear what you wanting - do you want a `<div>` that has 2 colors (say first 40% is red and 60% is green)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ye pretty much, lets say first 30%, second 30% and the static one 40%.

Comment: Paulie_D has just added the answer :) - just need to replace the % values with `@(Model.value1)%` etc (or you could use `<div>` elements within `<div>` elements (as inline-block)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ye i get that bit :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, with a linear gradient.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, red 40%, blue 40%, blue, 60%, green 60%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```